# Uploading a photo stream from camera into azure blob in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have the following simple application page that uses the phone camera to upload the taken photo to azure blob:

```
public partial class AddReport : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // blobs stuff
    string storageAccount = "MYACCOUNT";
    string storageKey = "MYKEY";
    string blobServiceUri = "http://MYACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net";
    CloudBlobClient blobClient;

    private Report newReport;
    public AddReport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        newReport = new Report();
        var credentials = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(storageAccount, storageKey);
        blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(blobServiceUri, credentials);
    }

    private void TakePhotoClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //The camera chooser used to capture a picture.
        CameraCaptureTask ctask;

        //Create new instance of CameraCaptureClass
        ctask = new CameraCaptureTask();

        //Create new event handler for capturing a photo
        ctask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(ctask_Completed);

        //Show the camera.
        ctask.Show();

    }

    void ctask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {

        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK && e.ChosenPhoto != null)
        {

            WriteableBitmap CapturedImage = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto);
            UploadToBlobContainer(e.ChosenPhoto);
        }
        else
        {
            //user decided not to take a picture
        }
    }
    private void UploadToBlobContainer(System.IO.Stream stream)
    {
        string containerName = "reportsPhotos";
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

        container.CreateIfNotExist(true, r =>
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                var blobName = "report" + newReport.ReportId.ToString();
                var blob = container.GetBlobReference(blobName);
                blob.Metadata["ReportId"] = newReport.ReportId.ToString();
                blob.UploadFromStream(stream, r2 =>
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                         newReport.Photo = container.Uri + "/" + blobName;
                    }));
            }));

    }
}
```

This is a simple case and I am not using SAS to authenticate, instead I save the key in the app itself (this is only for testing purposes) and also my blobs are publicly available.

when I run in debug mode it seems that everything is working, but the photo doesn't get uploaded to the blob. Also, I don't know how I can debug this to see if there was any error from the blob service.

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong ?

EDIT1: it seems that the container is not being created either. i've confirmed this using [azure blob explorer](http://blobexplorer.codeplex.com/)

EDIT2: I am getting a `System.Net.WebException : "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."`

Comment: What library are you using to access WA storage? Is it the WA Toolkit for Windows Phone? How do you know that it's not working? (What tools are you using to look for the blob in blob storage?)

Comment: @smarx i am using `WindowsPhoneCloud.StorageClient` and `Microsoft.Samples.Data.Services.Client` from the WAT for WP. To see if the blob was uploaded i am using azure blob storage explorer : http://blobexplorer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long hours I have finally discovered that the problem was with this line:

```
string containerName = "reportsPhotos";
```

According to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135715.aspx) all letters in a container name must be **lowercase**. 
Changing it to `reportsphotos` solved the issue

That was time well spent.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try just doing it like this instead:

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection-string
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the blob client
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob"
CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference("myblob");

// Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"path\myfile"))
{
    blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

This is from:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/#upload-blob

Comment: Doesn't seem relevant for a Windows Phone project.