# Windows Phone uploading images to azure blob service

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload a photo from my phone to azure blob.

Im using this link 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/upload-images-to-storage-wp8/

there is no error or a exception, it just i cant see it and i know the binding is correct,
even when i open the link of the image, there is no photo found.

there is a question similar to this one here 
[Upload image to Azure blob storage from Windows Phone. Not creating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037277/upload-image-to-azure-blob-storage-from-windows-phone-not-creating)

This is what I'm doing

```
PhotoChooserTask chooser;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Refresh();
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
private void PhotoChooserBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    chooser = new PhotoChooserTask();
    chooser.Completed += chooser_Completed;
    chooser.Show();
}

Stream stream = null;
void chooser_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    stream = e.ChosenPhoto;
    BitmapImage sourceImg = new BitmapImage();
    sourceImg.SetSource(stream);

    ProfileImage.Source = sourceImg;
}

async private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Images images = new Images() { Username = "7elbeh" };
    InsertImage(images);
}

private void RefreshBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Refresh();
}
```

please help.

Comment: Can you share the code for uploading the image to blob storage?

Comment: Every thing else is similar to this 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/upload-images-to-storage-wp8/
its the same anyway

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error, to solve i convert my Stream to array and use UploadFromByteArrayAsync

`byte[] array = imageStream.ToArray();
await blobFromSASCredential.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(array, 0, array.Length);`